# "Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence" occurs when posting xml in .jar but not in eclpise

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem where I am struggling, and I read many thread about "Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence" , such as 
[XML Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212729/xml-invalid-byte-1-of-1-byte-utf-8-sequence)
,
[MalformedByteSequenceException Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987535/malformedbytesequenceexception-invalid-byte-1-of-1-byte-utf-8-sequence) . But it does not solve my problem.

I have a web application(living in a paas cloud), and it is working fine to handle the request from the mobile clients(not developed by myself).

In order to test the server application, I write a client application(say test-client)based on Swing to post the xml data through HTTP to my server.

The strange problem is that when I run this test-client in eclipse , it works fine to submit the post and get the message from my server back.

But when I export it into Runnable jar, the exception is found in my server logs that " `org.dom4j.DocumentException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence. Nested exception: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.`"  when I post some xml data contains Chinese Character.

I believe this is relative to the difference encoding between my computer and eclipse.

Please note that

1.I do not have xml to read,instead I construct the xml data from an object

2.my general/preference/workspace is encoded as UTF-8. And I have `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` in my doPost;

3.I  hope to modify my test-client code to let it works fine since the server is now working fine in production with the mobile user.

Below is how I post the xml data

```
        URL url = new URL(address);
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) uc;
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");
        System.out.println("before POST:\n"+xmlstr);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        pw.write(xmlstr);
        pw.close();
```

And the xmlstr comes from below

(RequestTextMessage is a very easy class which only has getter, and one field of this Class will accept a input String, which may be Chinese):

```
 xmlStr= XMLRequest.textMessageToXml(msg);

public static String textMessageToXml(RequestTextMessage textMsg){
    xstream.alias("xml", textMsg.getClass());
    return xstream.toXML(textMsg);
}
   private static XStream xstream = new XStream(new XppDriver() {

        @Override
        public HierarchicalStreamWriter createWriter(Writer out) {  
            return new PrettyPrintWriter(out) {  
                boolean cdata = true;  

                protected void writeText(QuickWriter writer, String text) {  
                    if (cdata) {  
                        writer.write("<![CDATA[");  
                        writer.write(text);  
                        writer.write("]]>");  
                    } else {  
                        writer.write(text);  
                    }  
                }  
            };  
        }  
    });
```

For your information the exception from the server is below(I am sorry the exception is reverse):

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at wodinow.weixin.jaskey.co.CoreServlet.doPost(CoreServlet.java:161)
at wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.CommandService.generateResponseXML(CommandService.java:76)
at wodinow.weixin.jaskey.util.MessageUtil.parseXml(MessageUtil.java:52)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:335)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:439)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2947)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanCDATASection(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1614)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanData(XMLEntityScanner.java:1252)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1753)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:557)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:687)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
Nested exception:
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at wodinow.weixin.jaskey.co.CoreServlet.doPost(CoreServlet.java:161)
at wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.CommandService.generateResponseXML(CommandService.java:76)
at wodinow.weixin.jaskey.util.MessageUtil.parseXml(MessageUtil.java:52)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:335)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:458)
org.dom4j.DocumentException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence. Nested exception:     Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to choose the encoding used by your `PrintWriter`. Outside of Eclipse, your platform is presumably defaulting to something other than UTF-8.

Try this code:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Plus `conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");` which might be redundant as this seems configured elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It seems it works now, I will try convert it into exe and retry.  Actually, before I got your answer, I have tried below 4 ways: 1.xmlstr = URLEncoder.encode(xmlstr, "utf-8"); 2.chineseContent=URLEncoder.encode(chineseContent, "utf-8"); 3. conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");  4.conn.setRequestProperty("contentType", "utf-8");  they donot help, and some of them even makes it worse!. Would you please help to explain what is the difference between your answer and my attempts?

Comment: @Jaskey I'm not an expert on these classes, but I would suggest:  1. This escapes Chinese characters but is not equivalent to creating a UTF-8 string. 2. Same thing. 3. Not sure. 4. Looks like this advertises your text is UTF-8, but doesn't actually cause it to *be* UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @Duncan , Thank you! I tried in exe file and it works too. I have a question that when we use response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); it is that I will get a printwriter with UTF-8 encoded when I use response.getWriter();